# Could not create database trigger (AWS, RDS)

Tags: database, aws

How can I fix this issue about database trigger. I attached the screenshot for the info. Thanks so much for the help[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7liZ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to grant access for mysql user to create triggers. You can run below command in mysql using super privilege user(root)

```
GRANT TRIGGER ON <db_name>.* TO '<db_user>'@'localhost';
```

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Thanks! One more thing, I use RD on AWS for database and third party application like mysql workbench. Where can I run this command? Thanks so much again.

Comment: There must be some window where you can run queries. You can also raise a request at AWS to grant access for your mysql user.

Comment: I already put the command on the window in mysql workbench. Nothing happen. Maybe I will raise a request to AWS to grant access. Hmm. But I am using only a free tier on AWS, is there any chance to grant me an access for that? Thanks!

Comment: or maybe there's a command to restart or implement the changes right away? thanks!

Comment: AWS RDS [does offer trigger permissions to the master user](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.MasterAccounts.html) a/c, see also [this SE answer for more help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919907/can-i-create-trigger-in-an-rds-db).

Comment: AWS RDS free tier might be cheap but you might have to invest a bit more time if it's not a platform in common usage by other civicrm users. CiviCRM can be picky about some platforms. If you do stick with RDS, please contribute your learning & notes about any special challenges to https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/cloud-native